# Слово с "не"

Tags: грамматика

"Достаточно глубокое, хотя и не одинаковое влияние" — как должно писаться слово с «не»?

Answer (score 1):

Не с прилагательными, которые не имеют явного противопоставления (с союзом "а"), могут писаться и слитно, и раздельно в зависимости от смысла, который вкладывает автор. Но имея в виду наличие сопоставительного "хотя" -  я бы написала слитно.